# VBA Update a sub set of records

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following macro to place a "w" in column M (9) of the target record of a worksheet when colmun D gets the entry "Filled".

```
    Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

'If Status is "Filled" place a "w" in Results
'Range("D2:D" & lastrow) Is the Target it defines the column D as the target area
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D" & lastrow)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target <> "Filled" Then
        Target.Offset(, 9) = vbNullString
        Else: Target.Offset(, 9) = "w"
    End If
 End If
```

I would like to enter a "w" into col M of all records, that have the same entry in column K of the target row of the list, when anyone of these records
gets the entry "Filled" put in col D of one of these records.
[image]

Comment: This is a worksheet_change ...?

Comment: Yes, this is a worksheet_change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I does not seem that you got an answer. Your question is a bit ambiguous, but here is an idea:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range, lastRow As Long, tmpVal As Variant

lastRow = Me.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D2:D" & lastRow)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Filled" Then
        tmpVal = Target.Offset(0, 7).Value
        If Not Len(Trim(tmpVal)) = 0 Then
            For Each cell In Me.Range("K2:K" & lastRow)
                If cell.Value = tmpVal Then cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "w"
            Next cell
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the hlep. Nothing updated, I used the "lastrow" as in the originally posted code, is that consistent with your code?
I would post an image of before and after but can't figure how to do it here. When col D of the target gets "Filled" entered into it, col M should get a "w" entered into it for all records in the list, that have the same entry in col J as the target record has in col J.
So if the target col J had a "c" in it, all records with a "c" in col J would get a "w" in col M, when "Filled" is entered in col D.

Comment: I changed the code a bit. As you mentioned in your original post, your code is part of the Change event of the worksheet. The quick piece of code I gave you checks for which cell has been changed. If it is a cell in Column D, it checks if the entry is "Filled", then checks if the corresponding J cell has a "c" in it; if these conditions are met, the value in the corresponding M cell is changed to "w". As an example: if you key "Filled" in cell D4 and cell J4 contains a "c", then the value in M4 is changed to "w", otherwise it is set to nothing.

Comment: If I change "And Target.Offset(, 6)" to "And Target.Offset(, 7)", only the target record col M will up date to "W", otherwise nothing gets updated. But I trying to get all records that have a "c" in col K to update to "w" in col M. 
Also "C" was just an example entry, it could be any letter depending on the target letter selected. Thanks

Comment: I posted a before/after photo to the original post.

Comment: I hope I understood your request well. Each time there is an entry of "Filled" in a cell of the D column, you want to check all values in the corresponding range of column K, and for each cell of column K where the value is "a", to change the value of the corresponding M cell to "w". The new edit should do that. I continued to assume that you want the code in the Change event of the worksheet.

Comment: Yes, that functionally did it, I had to comment out Option Explicit, does that create any problems. Otherwise I get an error on "cell". 
As I mentioned in the previous post "a" was just an example hard coded entry, it is variable, could be any letter (a,b,c etc.) depending on what is entered on col K of the target record.

Comment: Sorry, I read again, and modified code. Should work fine now.

Comment: Oh no problem, worked great, really appreciated the help, thanks for jumping in.

Comment: My pleasure. Please consider up-voting or accepting the answer.

Comment: One last thing, is this what the procedure is doing?
1. Set tmpVal equal to col K of target record
2. Checks to see which records have col K value = the tmpVal value
3. If so set set two columns over from col J, col M, to "w"
What defines that the Offset(0,2) is referenced to col J not col D

Comment: You are almost correct. Offset(0,2) is referenced from Column K. Also, I have added a check in the Code to avoid putting a "w" for blank cell.

Comment: Ok, that is what I meant col K, what is the rule that "attaches" that Offset() to K? thanks for the update.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is, but the second digit for Offset is for the column displacement (positive to go to the right and negative to go to the left). So from Column D to go to Column K, there is 7 positions, and from K to M, 2 positions. BTW, I improved the code a bit.

Comment: But what is the rule that determines the starting reference column. Why didn't you use Offset(0,9) to reference from col D.

Comment: No specific rule. I just chose to start at column K; I did that because the variable cell holds a range value in column K. It would be hard to reference from column D when you work from column K.

Comment: Everything is working great, I was just going through the procedure to understand how it worked, it is excellent.

Comment: The latest version you posted, does the same thing as the previous version, correct. Handles blanks?

Comment: Yes, it handles blanks, but it checks first if the value in column K is blank (`If Not Len(Trim(tmpVal)) = 0 Then`), and if it is not, it runs through all cells of column K looking for cells with a similar value.